# How to use atoi() to convert an element of a char array to int?

Tags: c, pointers, atoi

Here is the code:

```
char *P_char = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

int i = 0;

for(i; i < 10; i++)
{
    P_char[i] = (char)(i + 48);
}
```

and here are some of the code that I have tried in order to use atoi

```
printf("The int result is: %d", atoi(P_char[4]));
```

and

```
int converted = atoi(P_char[4]);
printf("The int result is: %d", converted );
```

and

```
const char x = P_char[4];
int converted = atoi(x);
printf("The int result is: %d", converted );
```

But still doesn't work. I couldn't find out if atoi() is not supposet to be used for pointers. Is there such a fact?

**NOTE:** When I say doesn't work I mean program exits with error code instead of executing till the end.

Comment: you're trying to convert `char` to integer, but you need to pass `char*`

Comment: put `&P_char[4]` but may not work as you expect. it seems you try to convert a single `char` to int.

Comment: did you read atoi's manpage ? atoi converts a string to an integer, not a char to integer.  char to integer just requires casting...

Comment: See documentation on [`atoi()` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: What value are you expecting to get? If you want to get numbers from 48 to 58, you only need to print them out with %d. char and int only differ by size. char can hold 2^8 different numbers and int can hold 2^32, but they are both used to hold integer values.

Comment: @MattHammond I got the point. now I think what I am doing is holding my right ear with my left hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have such statement

```
const char x = P_char[4];
```

then to output the digit stored in x as an integer you can the following way

```
printf("The int result is: %d", x - '0' );
```

As for the function `atoi` then it is applied to strings not to a single character.

Comment: So, argument of atoi() should be null terminated? always?

Comment: @ozgur Yes, you are right. Though it can be applied to strings that have also alpha characters. For example applied to "10abc"; atoi will return 10.

Comment: Last question. I get char array from a console application. I need to get integers out of it. So I don't have a string like "xyz213" in my hand. I have a char array. In this case is it possible to use atoi()?

Comment: @ozgur Show what string you have and what integers you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

The function [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) is used to convert a C string to a number. It is declared as this:

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

You give a char value as a parameter. You must use something like this instead:

```
const char *s = "4711";
int i = atoi(s)
```